# Simple Android App consisting of two images

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm really new to Android and for my first project, I want to create an app that when opened, displays a full screen jpg (similar to a splash screen) and then another full screen JPG (which will have an image of the app interface).

THis is just for practice.

How do I make full screen JPGs appear when the app is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting background image to the rootlayout in your xml files.

```
android:background="@drawable\mySplash"
```

Then add a timer in your java file for like 2 seconds and show another layout.

Comment: Which `xml` file does this go in?

Comment: the xml file used in the activity pointed by the launcher intent tag activity in your manifest

Answer (score 2):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Use this two line before setcontentview

It will hide actionbar and status bar both.